# Block didn’t capture self in typeof,why?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

For this:

```
self.block = ^{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
};
```

There is a retain cycle obviously.

However,there is no retain cycle if the `self` is in the `typeof`:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
self.block = ^{
    __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    strongSelf.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
};
```

The self's `dealloc` is called even though the `self` is in the block.That means the block didn't capture `self` here.

Why?

Comment: Another thing you can also do if you want it to be "less confusing" is do `__strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;`. I do this for added clarity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`typeof` is not a function, it's a keyword and isn't used at runtime at all. All `__strong typeof(self)` is doing here is telling the compiler how to evaluate the symbol `strongSelf`. It doesn't cause any runtime code to be generated, because it doesn't matter at runtime what that type actually is. All those decisions are made at compile-time.

This is the same as defining something as `int x;` The runtime does not in any way have a reference to "int". It's just a C type.

`typeof` is technically a C extension, but Clang supports it as a keyword when in a gcc compatibility mode, which is the default. For more on the extension, see the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html).